# Asp Net Core Code-First error on Add-Migration InitialCreate to Azure

Tags: asp.net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db) when I run `Add-Migration InitialCreate` I get this error:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred
>   while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. --->
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'Blogs'.

`Blog` doesn't exist yet in the DB which is hosted in Azure, I expect `Add-Migration InitialCreate` will create the table `Blog`.  I have already run `Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations`

Here's all the code (except my database connection string):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace MemoCore
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<BloggingContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseBrowserLink();
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }

            var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>();
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer<BloggingContext>(connection); 

            using (var db = new BloggingContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
            {
                var blog = new Blog { Name = "william" };
                db.Blogs.Add(blog);
                db.SaveChanges();

                // Display all Blogs from the database 
                var query = from b in db.Blogs
                            orderby b.Name
                            select b;

                List<string> tmp = new List<string>();
                foreach (var item in query)
                {
                    tmp.Add(item.Name);
                }
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseMvc();
        }

        public class BloggingContext : DbContext
        {
            public BloggingContext(DbContextOptions<BloggingContext> options)
                : base(options)
            { }

            public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        }

        public class Blog
        {
            public int BlogId { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }

            public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        }

        public class Post
        {
            public int PostId { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Content { get; set; }

            public int BlogId { get; set; }
            public Blog Blog { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

------------> update --> 
So it works on one database called 'memo' but not another called 'memo2' there must be a difference between the databases somehow.

Comment: The migrations updates the database, you need to create the database on SQL Server before running the `Add-Migration` command.

Comment: @jcvegan The database exists, the table blog does not exist

Comment: @0x4f3759df please share how your initial migration is looking

Comment: @Set sorry I updated my question, its the Add-Migration InitialCreate that is failing.  So I don't have one.

Comment: @0x4f3759df `InitialCreate` in `Add-Migration InitialCreate` command is just a string name for migration files. Three files were added to your project under the Migrations directory. Check them.

Comment: @0x4f3759df the error appears when you run the add-migration command or when you try to update the database?

Comment: @jcvegan I don't have a Migrations directory.  I must have missed a command.  The error appears when I run 'add-migration initialcreate'.